# (Cython) Make the modulo argument optional in __pow__

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, pow

I am trying to define some built-in arithmetic operations for a `cdef class` in a Cython file.

At first I tried making the `__pow__` function like so:

```py
def __pow__(self, other, modulo=None):
    pass
```

But received the following error message when compiling:

> This argument cannot have a default value

(The argument the error message refers to is `modulo`)

Removing the default value for `modulo` allows the file to compile properly, but forces the user to provide the third argument, which is not only strange and annoying, but it also prevents the use of the `**` operator (`pow` would have to be used instead).

How can I implement `__pow__` in Cython such that the third argument is optional?

Comment: Maybe if you wrap the function in a decorator that has the optional parameter you might be able to fool the compiler, but I'd guess not...

Comment: You might be better [submitting a bug report](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues)

Comment: @WillDaSilva Lol, can't believe that. I added an answer with what I was mentioning, I believe that's what did it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to assign a default value to the third argument in `__pow__`: cython does that for you. When using the `**` operator or `pow()` with only 2 arguments, the third argument is set to `None`. You can then explicitly check for `None` and `return NotImplemented` if you don't intend to handle the 3-argument form of `pow`.

A simple example cython class, in _cclass_test.pyx:

```
# cython: language_level=3
cdef class Test:
    def __pow__(x, y, z):
        if z is None:
            print("Called with just x and y")
        else:
            print("Called with x, y and z")
```

And an example of its use:

```py
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
from _cclass_test import Test

t = Test()
t ** 5
pow(t, 5)
pow(t, 5, 3)
```

Output:

```sh
$ python cclass_test.py 
Called with just x and y
Called with just x and y
Called with x, y and z
```

(Tested with Cython version 0.29.12)

Comment: Under the hood, Cython is probably just not removing a `None`, rather than putting one there for you. (The [C API version](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Power) of `**` requires the caller to pass `None` as a third argument, and the [C hook](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyNumberMethods.nb_power) for implementing `**` takes 3 arguments unconditionally. Cython is probably just compiling your method and sticking it in the C slot directly.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a decorator to trick the cython compiler to think that that argument has no default value:

```
def trickster(func):
    def wrapper(self, other, modulo=None):
        return func(self, other, modulo)
    return wrapper


class MyClass:
   ...
   @trickster
   def __pow__(self, other, modulo):
       ...
```

Comment: Well, this tricked the compiler, but unfortunately it results in a segmentation fault  on import. As far as I can tell, Cython special methods cannot be decorated.

Comment: @WillDaSilva Uhm, that's strange. Did you try to use a "noop decorator"? I mean: replace `modulo=None` with just `modulo` and see if it gives a segmentation fault anyway?